# how to install wamp server?

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

Just installed Wampserver2.0 in my Win 7 and everything ran smoothly.

However, on our XP the system tray icon is in orange.

It says WAMP5 - Server online. But we are unable to Start any services.

If we Restart All Service the meter turns from red to yellow, and then red again.

This is the error message:

"Could not execute menu item (internal error) [Exception] Could not perform service action: The service has not been started."

Any Clues?

Comment: Check the apache error log, try running apache from the command line, it may give you a better error message.

Comment: i found some Good stuff regarding how to install WAMP Server on this link.. and how to set environment to start PHP work. Refer this link might help you.. http://code.freefeast.info/php-tutorials/setting-up-the-environment-for-php-php-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the latest version of both of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager
The 2010 Redist is used by Apache

FOR WAMP 32bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328

FOR WAMP 64bit
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)  http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523